# moodle.sty throwing errors when compiling tex file

Tags: moodle

Recently I've installed the moodle package and included it in a tex document. However, when I tried to compile my tex, the compiler throws a lot of errors concerning the moodle.sty file which I could not understand:

[image: Error image]

My tex file is a minimal working example, which doesn't involve any commands from the moodle package at all:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}
\begin{document}
123
\end{document}
```

I've uploaded the log file to https://pastebin.com/xnyvEiyt.

Can anyone give me some pointers on this? I'm completely lost here.

Comment: It compiles fine for me on a current tex system. Show the complete log-file of your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've edited the question to include the URL of the log file. Thanks.

Comment: You are using a quite new moodle from 2021 with a LaTeX from 2017. That is not a combination I can test, but I guess moodle is relying on newer code somewhere.

Comment: I updated my MikTeX installation and it works fine now. Yes it is the problem of an old installation. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Ulrike Fischer pointed out, it is due to moodle.sty being not compatible with an older MikTeX installation. A MikTeX update solved the issue.